# python3 - Named semaphores only within a given process?

Tags: python-3.x, semaphore, named

I know that there are python modules that allow the use of IPC and System V named semaphores. However, these resources exist at the system level. For my particular multithreaded python3 application, I need named semaphores in order to protect certain totally unrelated sections of code, but these semaphores should only be process-specific, not system-wide.

I have been unable to find any python code which implements named semaphores that solely exist within the current multithreaded process. Does anyone know of any code like that which has already been written?

I specifically want semaphores and not just a simple mutex, because I want to allow a certain number of concurrent accesses to these critical sections of code within the process, up to some configurable maximum number of accesses.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now see, based upon my discussion here with Ronald Smith, that I made a false assumption. I incorrectly thought that there is only one, shared underlying semaphore instance per python interpreter. Now that I see that this is not the case, I understand that it's possible to utilize multiple semaphores per process.

I still want named semaphores, however, to take care of the case where more than one section of my code might share a single semaphore, while other sections might want to use other semaphores. So I implemented a named-semaphore wrapper around `threading.BoundedSemaphore` in order to handle this case.

I have removed my earlier code (which approximated named semaphores via named queues), and I've replaced it with the following code which implements named, process-specific semaphores ...

```
def _out(msg=None):
    if msg:
        sys.stdout.write(msg)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    # Just in case ...
    sys.stdout.flush()

def _err(msg=None):
    if msg:
            sys.stderr.write(msg)
    sys.stderr.write('\n')
    # Just in case ...
    sys.stderr.flush()

# This factory is used by the semaphore-based locker, below.
class MyNamedSem(object):
    __uniqueid = uuid.uuid4()

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name, value=1):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('missing semaphore name')
        if not value or value < 1:
            raise ValueError('value must be a positive integer')
        with threading.RLock():
            sem = cls._cache.get(name, None)
            if not sem:
                sem = MyNamedSem(name, value=value, _uid=cls.__uniqueid)
            cls._cache[name] = sem
            return sem

    def __init__(self, name, value=1, _uid=None):
        # This makes it impossible, for all intents and purposes,
        # to get an instance of this class without going through
        # the factory method.
        assert(_uid == self.__class__.__uniqueid), "use the 'get' factory method"

        self._name = name
        self._s    = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=value)
MyNamedSem._cache = {}

class MySemLock(object):

    def __init__(self, name, maxaccesses=1, timeout=None, verbose=True):
        if name:
            self._name = name
        else:
            raise ValueError('!!! missing semaphore name')
        if not maxaccesses or maxaccesses < 1:
            raise ValueError('!!! max accesses must be a positive integer')
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._sem     = MyNamedSem.get(self._name, value=maxaccesses)._s
        self._verbose = verbose

    def acquire(self):
        try:
            rc = self._sem.acquire(blocking=True, timeout=self._timeout)
            if rc:
                return True
            elif self._timeout:
                if self._verbose:
                    _err('!!! {} timeout'.format(self))
                return False
            else:
                if self._verbose:
                    _err('!!! {} failed'.format(self))
                return False
        except Exception as e:
            if self._verbose:
                _err('!!! {} acquire exception: {}'.format(self, e))
            return False
        return True

    def release(self):
        try:
            # The only way this release call should fail is if
            # release has been called too many times.
            self._sem.release()
            if self._verbose:
                _out('=== {} released'.format(self))
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            if self._verbose:
                _err('!!! {} release exception: {}'.format(self, e))
            return False

    # Dijkstra's traditional names ...
    P = acquire
    V = release

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.acquire():
            return self
        else:
            return None

    def __exit__(self, tp, val, tb):
        self.release()
        if tp:
            _err('!!! {} exception: {}\n{}\n{}'.format(self, tp, val, tb))
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<semlock: {}>'.format(self._name)
```

I would use it like this:

```
with MySemLock('section0', maxaccess=10):
    # Critical section which allows 10 concurrent accesses.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `threading.Semaphore`?

You only need a *name* if a semaphore is to be accessed by another *process*.

Threads by definition share an address space, so they can have access to basically everything in the right scope.

**Edit:**
Note that `Semaphore` is a class. So each call to `threading.Semaphore()` creates a *separate instance* of the `Semaphore` class.

Comment: I have several critical sections in my multithreaded application. For the purpose of this discussion, call them "section0", "section1" and "section2". I don't want the semaphore protecting "section0" to block "section1" or "section2". I want each one to be controlled by its own semaphore.

Comment: Why not use a semaphore for each section?

Comment: Because calling `threading.Semaphore()` only manages one, single semaphore that is shared throughout the entire application, correct? In other words, calling it in 5 different places in my code will still only refer to that one, single semaphore. It's equivalent to calling `threading.RLock` in that respect ... that's one, single lock which is shared throughout the whole application. Or am I misunderstanding? Also, if I ever want more than one critical section to be protected by one, single semaphore, with other critical sections protected by different  ones, I'm out of luck.

Comment: Yes, it's a separate instance, but I thought that given the way the python handles threading via the GIL, I thought (maybe incorrectly) that there is only one underlying locking resource per python interpreter, for each lock, and that each instance referrs to that one, single locking resource. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HippoMan *When in doubt, check the source.* Look at `threading.py` in your Python installation. You will see that neither `RLock` nor `Semaphore` use a shared lock.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I have just gotten rid of that named-queue implementation and replaced it, above, with my new named-semaphore implementation. Thank you!